# AutoSuggest in C# DataGridView is not showing suggestions

Tags: c#, datagridview, autocomplete

I have a C# DataGridView into which I am trying to put an AutoSuggest textbox. My code looks correct and is executing, but the dropdown never appears. Here is the current event code:

```
private void myGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox) e.Control;
    var colItem = GetColumnItem(myGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
    if (colItem == "Cell Type")
    {
        _autoCompleteCellType.Clear();
        _autoCompleteCellType.AddRange(new[] { "Wrappable", "Never Wrap", "Weblink" });
        textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = _autoCompleteCellType;
        textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
}
```

All seems to be good, except that no dropdown appears. I'm stymied. Any thoughts?

Comment: Refresh the textbox - e.g. textbox.Refresh()

Comment: Refreshing didn't make a difference.

Comment: did you write the event handler correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `myGrid.DefaultCellStyle.Wrapmode` to anything but `DataGridViewTriState.True` **before** triggering the `EditingControlShowing` event.

I have no references or knowledge of the inner mechanics, I just debugged blindly until that revealed itself as the root of the malfunction.